# Using getCharPositionInLine() with leading spaces in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I am writing grammar for a script which is based on VBScript.
In the script, the variable assignment is done in the usual manner of `i=10` and in addition a variation with: `Set i=10`

The method calls can be done in several ways along with calling methods on objects, like:
`Another(10).Call(20).Chain(30)`

I consider 'Set' as a keyword in my grammar. However, in some pre-defined calsses, the developer is allowed to name the method as 'Set', so, there maybe calls like (let me mark this as `line A`):
`Another(10).Call(20,30).Set 40,50`

my grammar:

```
definition: body EOF;
body: NL_WS* bodyElement NL_WS*;
bodyElement: statement (NL_WS+ statement)* ;

statement: assignment | chainCall;
assignment: (START_SET)? IDENTIFIER WS? EQUALS WS? (chainCall | VALID_NUMBER) ;

chainCall: methodCall ('.' methodCall)* ;
methodCall: IDENTIFIER WS? LPAREN? WS? argumentList? WS? RPAREN?;

argumentList: VALID_NUMBER (WS? COMMA WS? VALID_NUMBER)* ;
START_SET: 'Set' WS;
VALID_NUMBER: [1-9] NUMBER? ;
IDENTIFIER: LETTER LETTER_OR_DIGIT*;

LETTER: [a-zA-Z_];
NUMBER: [0-9];
LETTER_OR_DIGIT: [a-zA-Z0-9_];
EQUALS: '=' ;
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
COMMA: ',';

NL_WS: WS? NEWLINE WS?;
NEWLINE: [\r\n];
WS: [ \t]+;
```

This fails in what I have marked as `line A` (where Set is a method call inside an object):
`line 10:24 mismatched input 'Set ' expecting IDENTIFIER`

1) I am not able to understand why. My thinking is that as in the `assignment` rule, the `(START_SET)?` is defined at the beginning, it should expect Set at the beginning and so, the method call at the end should match with `IDENTIFIER`.

2) When I try with `getCharPositionInLine`, like:

`START_SET: {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? 'Set' WS;`

it works fine, but, I have to deal with another problem. That is, there maybe leading whitespaces before the 'Set' assignment, like:
`'    Set k=10'`

and in such cases, it fails saying:

`line 16:8 mismatched input 'k' expecting {<EOF>, '.', NL_WS}`

(in this case, I think it matches with `chainCall` and not `assignment` which is understandable as it is not the first character in line).

So, is there an alternate method which will be like 'first character in line minus spaces'?

I also tried,`START_SET: {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? WS? 'Set' WS;`
thinking that the initial `WS?` will cover the first character in line, but I get the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a method to deal with this issue. I wrote what is called pre-processor which strips all the leading spaces in a line and then have that parsed by ANTLR. This way I could use `{getCharPositionInLine() == 0}` successfully.
Also, this helped in keeping the grammar simpler. 
HTH.